# How to randomly initialize layers in pretrained model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I am using Xception model with pre initialized weights trained on ImageNet as so:

```
model = keras.applications.Xception(
    weights='imagenet',
    input_shape=(150,150,3)
)
```

Now I Would like to take specific layer (by its name, using `model.get_layer(layerName)`) and then **reinitialize its weights to completely random one**.

What is the simplest way to do so, and if it is even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a reinitialize function like this:

```py
def reinitialize_layer(model, initializer, layer_name):
    layer = model.get_layer(layer_name)    
    layer.set_weights([initializer(shape=w.shape) for w in layer.get_weights()])
```

Instead of `layer_name` you could also work with the layer index. You could also extend the function such that it takes a list of layer names, if you like to reinitialize more than one layer.

Usage example:

```py
import keras

model = keras.applications.Xception(
    weights='imagenet',
    input_shape=(299,299,3)
)

# zeros as illustrative example, change to something else
initializer = keras.initializers.Zeros() 

# check pretrained weights
print(model.get_layer("predictions").get_weights())

# change "predictions" to whatever layer name you like to use instead
reinitialize_layer(model, initializer, "predictions") 

# check weights after reinitialization
print(model.get_layer("predictions").get_weights())

model.compile(...)
model.fit(...)
```